# How to call a function using JPA Criteria API?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, criteria-api

I am creating a specification which returns the records for the ids provided by the db function GET_RECORD_IDS. I am providing my code snippet below-

```
return ((root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.and(root.get("id").in(
criteriaBuilder.function("GET_RECORD_IDS", List.class, criteriaBuilder.literal(str))))
```

But this code results in the error ***set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE***. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the following code makes it work-

```
return ((root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.and(root.get("id").in(
criteriaBuilder.function("select id from GET_RECORD_IDS", List.class, criteriaBuilder.literal(str))))
```